# Migrating Eth0 Private IP to new instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-vpc

I have a Windows instance (m1.medium) running in a VPC in AWS with one Network Interface (eth0).

I am trying to see if there is a way (or a workaround?) to migrate the private IP (IE: 10.80.78.0/24 subnet)from this instance to another instance?

I know with Elastic Network Interfaces (eth1) you can hotswap the ENI as needed between different nodes.

I have a bad feeling that this instance will need to be terminated, to allow us to migrate the IP to another node.

Before doing so though, I was wondering if anyone has ever dealt with this before-and maybe has a solution? Right now all services for a particular application are pointing to the above Private IP, so launching a new instance in the same subnet and updating our code to reflect the new IP (in Production) would be to hasty (at this juncture)..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's apparently no consolation, here.

Only secondary IP addresses can be moved around without terminating the instance.

> Unlike a primary private IP address, you can reassign a secondary private IP address from one network interface to another and from one instance to another.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html</sup>

The Network Interfaces option in the console will also greet you with a greyed-out "detach" button for primary interfaces.

> You can detach secondary (eth*N*) network interfaces when the instance is running or stopped. However, you can't detach the primary (eth0) interface.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#detach_eni</sup>